# Storing the sorted indices of a 2-D array in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting

Say I have an `n x n` array `A`.  Is there a "nice" way to do the following?

```
A_flat = reshape(A, [1, numel(A)]);
[dummy, A_index] = sort(A, 'descend');
A_row = mod(A_index - 1, size(A, 1)) + 1;
A_col = floor((A_index - 1) / size(A, 1));
```

By "nice", I mean am looking for a way that doesn't use for-loops, doesn't use mod/floor, and is efficient.  (I'm new to MATLAB, and still not sure what functions exist and what kinds of things to expect built-in functions for.)

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish in the example code. Can you give an example of what you'd like as an output for a small input?

Comment: `mod` _is_ very nice :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding your code correctly, you are given a 2D matrix and it is your task to sort the values in this 2D matrix.  The way you are currently performing this is to unroll the values into a vector, sort this vector and calculate where the corresponding 2D locations would be.

That can be achieved by [`ind2sub`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html).  When you are using `reshape`, the unrolling into the vector is done in a column-major format so that columns of the matrix are stacked together.  When performing the sorting, this is also doing using the column-major layout.  In a similar fashion, `ind2sub` takes in column-major indices and produces the equivalent row and column locations that map to each index.

The second output of `sort` would give you the locations of where each value would appear in the sorted result in a column-major format.  Just take this result and directly use `ind2sub`:

```
%// Your code
A_flat = reshape(A, [1, numel(A)]);
[dummy, A_index] = sort(A, 'descend');

%// New
[A_row, A_col] = ind2sub(size(A), A_index);
```

Comment: Minor comment. I'd argue that your use of `mod` and `floor` is probably faster. I believe `ind2sub` uses loops under the hood so performance-wise, you should stick with what you have. For code readability, then stick with what I wrote. It clearly shows what you're after.